# Apple App Site association not working

Tags: ios-universal-links, app-site-association

App Search API Validation Tool of "Apple" is not validating my domain.

https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool

I am using universal links but "Link to Application" is showing me "Error".(http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1719847/330979a43c4c6b2766da1e703447ee04)

Here is my "apple-app-site-association" file code.

`{"applinks": {"apps": [],"details": {"XXXXXXXXXX.com.streatmanagement.threadshare": {"paths": ["*"]}}}}`

Can someone please solve my query or send the sample of "apple-app-site-association" valid code?

Answer (score 6):

Apple's API validation tool compares your website's association file to a store listing. If your app is not yet publicly available the error you listed will be displayed.

Your apple-app-site-association has a small typo where you specify the details (it should be an array). I also assume you're replacing the XXXX's with your app ID.

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "APPID.BUNDLEID",
                "paths": [ "*" ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Even if you get this error from Apple's validation tool, you can test Universal links. If your Universal Link does not work on your test device you need to inspect the device logs when you fresh install it and make sure your `apple-app-site-association` is available at the root of your site via https with no redirects. Sometimes there is issue if the content-type is not application/json (but the file name should remain exactly `apple-app-site-association`).

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. First of all app's first version is live on app store with same bundle id. Yes those XXXX is for appId. I am curious to know why it does keep showing the same error. I found very less documentation related this topic.

Comment: As the site says sometimes it takes time to update. Do the Universal Links actually work?

Comment: I didn't checked yet in device. But on simulator does not works. I will check with device and let you know.

Comment: Simulator won't work for Universal Links so yes you should check with device!

Comment: The simulator actually _does_ work as of Xcode 8 and iOS 10. Good news :)

Comment: ok you need to do some debugging - did you change `details` to be an array? Is your file accessible over https? Are you able to curl `apple-app-site-association`? Did you put the domains as applinks in Capabilities? What do your device logs say on install (uninstall and reinstall to see the link check)?

Comment: @bradkratky, about your comment "apple-app-site-association is available at the root of your site via https ". This should work also in http, correct?

Comment: @user2924482 no, Universal Links requires https

Comment: @bradkratky, does the apple-app-site-association needs to be sign with the SSL certificated ?

Comment: @user2924482 no the file itself doesn't need to be signed last time I checked. Just the site itself has to provide the file over https

Comment: @bradkratky, does the links needs to have https ?, for example `https ://mydomain.com/myapp.html` to be redirect to the app by the universal links?